# Unable to grab attribute from html tag using selenium webdriver (Java)

Tags: html, selenium

I would like to write a selenium test to see if an HTML tag will show hidden or not.  The tag changes as follows:

Hidden state:

```
<div id="gameboard" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Shown state:

```
<div id="gameboard" style="display: block;">
```

I tried to use the following code to help me pull the attribute for the test:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("gameboard")).getAttribute("style"));
```

Unfortunately nothing prints out. When I try to pull id its gives me the right attribute.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Try to wait for the page to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I am getting result without any error.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gameboard" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="gameboard" style="display: block;">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Selenium Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HowToGetStyleValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver 4");
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.get("file:///Users/xxx/Downloads/testing.html");
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("gameboard")).getAttribute("style"));
    }
}
```

Result

```
display: none;
```